# Mvc with Web Api - No type was found that matches the controller named

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to add a web service to my mvc project using web api.
Upon project creation, I chose Mvc + Web Api for that.

However, I can't access the api controller, I keep getting this error:

```
<Error>
    <Message>
        No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://www.myapp.app/api/sms'.
    </Message>
    <MessageDetail>
        No type was found that matches the controller named 'sms'.
    </MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

My `global.asax`:

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
BundleMobileConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

My `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

My `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

}
```

My Api controller:

```
public class SmsController : ApiController
{
    private DbContext db = new DbContext();

    // GET: api/Sms
    public IQueryable<Sms> GetSms()
    {
        return db.Sms;
    }
    ...
}
```

Naturally I'm trying to access the api via `http://www.myapp.app/api/sms`.

I literally tried everything I could think of, and read about every related question on SO and other forums, but nothing helped me.
I'm pretty sure it has to do with my application url, which is not the regular `localhost:port`, I changed it to `www.myapp.app` and it runs on port 80.

For that, I had to change the IIS bindings to look like `*:80:www.myapp.app` and also added this entry to the `drivers/etc/hosts` file: `127.0.0.1 www.myapp.app`.

At this point I'm pretty sure this is what is causing my problem.

Any ideas?

Application Insights says my requests are apparently being mapped correctly:

[image: Application Insights saying there were request attempts]

Also it shows that the following requests were mapped to this controller and action:

GET sms
GET Sms/GetSms
GET sms/getsms
GET sms/Index
GET Sms
GET /api/sms

Comment: Does it work in your local machine with ***localhost***?

Comment: I'm trying on my local machine, I just changed the project url from localhost to myapp. With a new project, leaving the url untouched, yes it works. I can;t figure out how to setup web api with a custom url. The MVC controllers are mapped just fine, the WebApi controllers however...

Comment: if using convention-based routing then you need to name the mehod `Get()` if you want `GET http://www.myapp.app/api/sms` to work

Comment: but if OP use attribute routing like I answered that must not be problem with method name, but strill not working

Comment: VIsual studio generated this controller automatically, and based on how webapi works I should not have to rename the requests. GetSms implies that any GET request to Sms will be mapped to that action. It is pretty much like having the Controller suffix in controllers. I could Have GetThisIsATests and access it with /api/thisisatest and it would work. I could also have PostBlaBla and access it with a POST to /api/blabla

Comment: are there multiple GET functions in your controller? or you can try routing by Action name by adding another entry in webapiconfig.cs for it

Comment: Can you comment out or remove the injection on **RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);** in **Global.asax.cs** and re-run?  Does that at least get WebApi to serve?

Comment: @KarthikGanesan No, only 1 get.

Comment: @StinkyTowel tried that, no luck.

Comment: Remove the binding but leave to host file entry and retry

Comment: If I remove the binding the project wont even run, there must be a binding.
I tested on a new project with pretty much the same congifuration, hosts file included, and it worked. This is killing me :/

Comment: @victor did you try adding another Routes entry with Action as part of url?routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute routing

```
public class SmsController : ApiController
{
    private DbContext db = new DbContext();

    // GET: api/Sms
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/sms")]
    public IQueryable<Sms> GetSms()
    {
        return db.Sms;
    }
    ...
}
```

if port number `80` then no need to add it but if different that `80` then the url

`http://www.myapp.app:portnumber/api/sms`

Comment: add port number to the url

Comment: try accessing  http://www.myapp.app:portnumber/Home/Index is it working ?

Comment: Still nothing =/ I'm pretty sure it has something to do with me defining a different iis url, because I tested it in a new project and the exact same setup works just fine

Comment: /Home/Index works just fine. It works fine for MVC constrollers, it doesn't work for WebApi controllers

Comment: you can try restoring the nuget packages, try adding webapi again.

Comment: @NitinBourai I agree with you

Comment: It says "Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.5.2.3' already exists in project 'MVC'"

Comment: remove and then restore

Comment: Still nothing... Damn

Comment: try fresh url in your iis, may this help

Comment: @Mostafiz still nothing